# OrderByChild on a query after filtering list using Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have an Ionic mobile app that gets its data from a Firebase back end. On one page I get a list of stations with location and current price for each station. What I want to do is filter the list by location, and then order it by price.

```
    let query = this.db.list('/stations', {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'distanceFromUser',
        endAt: 50.0,
        limitToFirst: 20
      }
    });

    this.stations = query, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'currentPrice',
      }
    }
```

This code is obviously not working, but it kind of displays what I would like to accomplish. First create a query with the 20 closest stations in a 50 km radius, and then order this list by currentPrice.

Is there any way to make this happen with Firebase?

Comment: As Saksham says, the common workaround to Firebase's limit of one sort/filter property is to combine the values you want to filter on in one property. But combining two numerical values in there in a way that allows performing a range query on them is quite uncommon. The only time I've seen that is in Geofire, which combines a latitude and longitude into a single queryable property.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a new child combining the two like distanceFromUser_currentPrice and then use it in the query.

Also, your query for finding 20 closest stations in a 50 km radius isn't gonna work because endAt will also return stations with distance like 150.0, 250.0 etc.